# Flags in objdump output of object file

Tags: linux, elf, objdump

There is this output of objdump on some object file:

```
$ objdump -h main.o

main.o:     file format elf32-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         0000000b  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000040  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000040  2**2
                  ALLOC
  3 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, CODE
```

What do these flags CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD and so on mean?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you see is the interpretation of the combination of ELF segment flags, section type and section flags for each section in the object file.

- `LOAD` means that the section resides in a loadable segment, i.e. its content could be read from the file into memory when a process is created

Section flags are well documented in the [Chapter 4](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.sheader.html) of the System V Application Binary Interface, although under slightly different names from what `objdump` shows.

- `CODE` means that the section contains executable code; it is indicated by the `SHF_EXECINSTR` flag in the section header
- `DATA` means that the section is not executable but is writable, indicated by the presence of the `SHF_WRITE` flag
- `READONLY` means that the section is neither executable nor writtable and should be placed in read-only memory pages
- `ALLOC` means that the section occupies memory, e.g. memory pages are actually allocated to hold the section content when a process is created, indicated by the `SHF_ALLOC` flag. Some sections, e.g. those containing debug information, are not read into memory during normal program execution and are not marked as `ALLOC` to save memory.

Sections of type `SHT_PROGBITS` have corresponding content in the file and are shown as `CONTENTS`. Some sections does not have corresponding content in the file, e.g. the `.bss` section, which is of type `SHT_NOBITS`.

The `.text` section contains the program executable code. It is show as `CONTENTS` since it is of type `SHT_PROGBITS`. Memory should be reserved for this section since it is `ALLOC` and its contents should be loaded from the file since it is placed in a `LOAD`-able segment. Program code is generally non-modifiable and hence the section is placed in read-only memory. It contains instructions that are to be executed and hence the `CODE` flag.

*Initialised* variables with static storage class go into the `.data` section. Their initial values are stored in the file and read from there as the process is created. In C/C++ these are global variables, static local variables and C++ static member variables that are initialised appropriately, e.g. `static int a = 10;`. Fortran places initialised `SAVE`-d variables and `COMMON` blocks, which are given intiial value with a block `DATA` statement there.

The `.bss` section (historic name, abbreviation from *Block Started by Symbol*) is the most simple one. It holds *uninitialised* variables with static storage class. It is a section of type `SHT_NOBITS` and takes no space in the file. Memory is `ALLOC`-ated for it but nothing is read from the file to prepopulate the memory - it just stays all zeroes as delivered by the kernel memory allocator.

Constants usually go into the `.rodata` section (not present in your example), which looks like `.data` but is not marked as writable and is thus shown as `READONLY`.

Comment: the link #2 is broke now. :(

Comment: I tried running objdump -h on an relocatable file (raw .o file, i.e. a file without program headers), and it still listed sections (eg. .text) with the LOAD attribute. So it is not clear to me what the difference between LOAD and ALLOC is. Maybe it's just LOAD = ALLOC && CONTENTS

Comment: @TroelsFolke, yes, the BFD library that `objdump` is built upon has a hardcoded logic that sections that occupy space in both the binary (`CONTENTS`) and memory (`ALLOC`) should go into a loadable segment (`LOAD`). `LOAD` is a segment attribute, and since `.o` files have no program headers, its presence in the output of `objdump` is "fake" (or rather assumed).

Comment: @TroelsFolke, it is also worth mentioning that what `objdump` shows are abstract BFD sections with abstract attributes built by combining attributes of the elements of the underlying object file type. Thus, `readelf` is better suited for analysing ELF files.

Answer (score 5):

Found pieces of information on `Ubuntu elf man page` and this is just my understanding.
I think they are information from both the `program header` and `section header`.

```
LOAD: may correspond to PT_LOAD in the Program header table. Brief description:
It specifies the type of that particular element in the program header table.
The array element specifies a loadable segment

ALLOC: may correspond to SHF_ALLOC in the section table. Brief description:
Its specifies the flag of that particular element in the section header.
This  section  occupies  memory during process execution.

CODE/ DATA: indicates the belonging segment

READONLY: specifies a read-only segment

CONTENTS: I didn't find anything to conclude.
```

Hope this helps