# Compiled file is too large [202493852 bytes] error from on-line submission

Tags: c++

While using a 2-D array, I tried using a static array assigning -1 to it's first element:

```cpp
int dp[5001][5001] = {-1};   //setting dp[0][0] to -1
int calc(int i, int j){
    //Some operations are happening here which utilize dp array.
}
int main(){
   cout << calc(0,0);
}
```

When I submit this code-snippet as a solution online, I get `Can't compile file:  Compiled file is too large [202493852 bytes]`.

But, when I just gave it a try by setting the value of dp in main()

```cpp
int dp[5001][5001];
int calc(int i, int j){
    //Some operations are happening here which utilize dp array.
}
int main(){
   dp[0][0] = -1;
   cout << calc(0,0);
}
```

The above snippet was successfully accepted and compiled.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Aside of the problem, note that `= {-1};` will assign `-1` to only the first element and assign `0` to all other elements.

Comment: can you reproduce it with a compiler outside of codeforges? eg here https://godbolt.org/z/av79Wha8G. Online competition sites are notoriously useless for actual debugging

Comment: and don't declare such a large array. Allocate memory dynamically instead

Comment: I am 100% confident that correct "solution" for this codeforces puzzle, whatever it is, does ***not*** require a huge array like that. This is why codeforces rejects your solution.

Comment: Also: You should be careful about `memset`ing integers. Memsetting them to zero works fine, memset'ing them to -1 "happens" to work but is really icky. Memsetting them to any other value will fail.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OP says the code with `int dp[5001][5001];` runs on codeforces. (OP doesn't say it is accepted though)

Comment: May I please remind those who downvote a question explain what they believe should be done to improve it. The question is not about should or should not one allocate static arrays, or use global variables, or rely on an integer -1 representation of a particular architecture, or how one should submit solutions to a competition (that I never heard of, for one). The question is why the binary file is large in one case and small in another. In the narrow sense, it's a perfectly valid and useful question. shishak, you could make the examples identical by writing `dp[0][0] = -1;`, not memset.

Comment: Your question will also be better if you remove the incorrect statement that the first example initializes every element of the array to -1. Only the first one, at (0,0), is initialized, the rest is zeroed out.

Comment: @kkm: He can't remove that line, since that line _is_ the core of the problem he's encountering

Comment: @MooingDuck, this is incorrect. The size of the compiled binary cannot become larger because an array initializer contains too few elements.

Comment: @MikeVine Not fully true; actually any integer value having all four bytes at the same value will work, too, e. g. 0x07070707, so there are in total 256 numbers that work ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua Sure. But I'm not convinced that `memset`'ing an int to 7 and expecting it to have the value 117901063 is reasonable - its either a bug (as in they programmer misunterstood what they were doing) or its totally opaque to the reader whats going on. Maybe I should've said instead of "fail" -> "fail what you'd naively expect it to be"

Comment: @kkm: The difference isn't that the initializer has too few elements, the difference is that one _has an initializer array_. To fix the "too few elements" and retain a MVCE, you'd have to have an initializer list with 25010001 items in your source code.

Comment: @MikeVine Wasn't meant fully serious... Actually I intended `memset`ting to 117901063, not to 7.

Comment: @MooingDuck: the core of the problem the OP _is_ encountering is the executable file is too large. When you say “he cannot remove _this line_,” you may be referring to either of my two recommendations: replace memset with an assignment, or remove the incorrect assertion in the question that the initializer in the first example has the same effect as the memset in the second. Neither of these will make the problem go away. I have an impression your original comment was directed to me by mistake.

Comment: @kkm "Your question will also be better if you remove the incorrect statement that the first example initializes every element of the array to -1." The initializer list is whats increasing the binary size.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Exactly. It's the presence of the initializer what sends the array into the initialized data section, not the erroneous paragraph in the question text or comments. If that paragraph is removed, the problem with the code size is not going away. Sorry, I'm getting weary of this nitpicking. I said only what I said, without anything implied beyond that, clearly: "Remove the text because it is misleading and says the opposite to what the code is doing." That's it. I'm not going to argue over any possible reading of my comment. Human language in inherently imprecise.

Comment: @MooingDuck, and if you want to say that "remove this _statement_" can be read as "C++ statement" or "English language statement," I'll think for a minute or two to find an objection, which is that neither initializer nor a declaration in C++ is a statement. But this will be a violation of the Grice maxims, and I'll be condemned to be frozen in philosophical hell with Kant's works read to me aloud non-stop beyond the end of days. I certainly do not want this fate! :)

Comment: @kkm: "can be read as "C++ statement" or "English language statement," Well that explains my confusion! I thought you meant to remove the C++ initializer, my mistake. Sorry!

Comment: @MooingDuck No biggie! I felt something is off, but could not grok what. Glad the misunderstanding is resolved! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you declare a static array *with an initializer*, like

```
int dp[5001][5001] = {-1};
```

the whole array is put into a data section of the executable file. Its size is (5001×5001=25010001) × `sizeof(int)` of your compiler. If `sizeof(int)==8`, then the size of the array in bytes, 200080008, comes close to the limit you cited. There is other stuff in the binary, in the end.

On the other hand, an array *without an initializer* from the second example

```
int dp[5001][5001];
```

is not allocated any data space in the executable file; instead, there is just a small record that tells the loader to allocate a zero-initialized block of memory of this size in the process' address space when it starts.

This optimization is not mandatory, but both ELF and Windows PE binaries use it. The initialized data segment is typically called `.data`, and the uninitialized `.bss`.

---

A tiny hands-on experiment to show the concept¹:

```
// Save me as bss.cc
int without_initializer[10000][10000];      // 100 million elements.
int with_initializer[1000][1000] = { 42 };  // 1 million elements.

/*
Run and see:
$ c++ -c -o bss.o bss.cc
$ ls -l bss.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 kkm kkm 4001008 2021-05-18 06:00:19 bss.o
$ objdump -h bss.o
bss.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         003d0900  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          17d78400  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  003d0940  2**5
                  ALLOC
  3 .comment      0000001d  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  003d0940  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
$ rm bss.cc bss.o
*/
```

The `.data` section has the size 0x3d0900=4000000 bytes. Apparently, this compiler's `sizeof(int)` is 4. It also has the `LOAD` flag, which means that it [must be loaded from the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197071/1149924), as is well explained in the linked answer.

ls(1) shows that the object file size is just a little larger than the same 4000000 bytes, with a bit of extra space taken by headers and the little `.comment` section, probably identifying the compiler (objdump(1) can dump its contents, if you're so curious).

The `.bss` section has the size 0x17d78400=400000000, exactly equal `sizeof(without_initializer)`. It has the `ALLOC` flag to tell the loader that it must be in the process' address space, but not the `LOAD` flag, which means there is nothing to load from the file.

You may note that the `.bss` section occupies exactly 0 bytes in the file: it's offset and that of the following `.comment` section are both 0x003d0940.

¹ Using Linux commands and its ELF format. On Windows, use `cl /c bss.cc` then `dumpbin /headers bss.obj` from the [Native Tools command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell) if you have Visual Studio handy.

Comment: @MikeVine, thanks, I reworded the answer. I focused on the initializer being present or not. And you are right, of course. I wanted to answer precisely the question asked, but worded it kinda sloppily. :)

Comment: thank you for such an informative answer.